# An issue involving writing and loading csv file in the Flask server

Tags: dataframe, rest, flask, io

I am trying to write a module to generate a csv file in the Flask server and then read it as a data frame for next steps. The things I am doing is getting the response from the PubChem REST service to generate each row and then write them into a csv file one by one. Once the process is complete, the module will save and re-open it to read it as a pandas data frame:

```
def bioassay_post(identifier_list, identifier='cid', output='csv'):
    """ uses PubChem's PUG-Rest service to obtain assay summaries for a target set of chemicals
    via a POST request.

    identifier_list: a list of chemical identifiers, the type of identifier should match with that outlined
    in the 'identifier' argument with the default being PubChem Compound Identifier (CID).

    identifier: the chemical identifier (e.g., cid, smiles, etc.) of the chemicals in 'identifier_list'. Can be any chemical identifier
    as outlined in the PubChem PUG-Rest documentation.  Default=cid

    output: the output format (e.g., csv, json, etc.) of the

    """

    # convert list of identifiers to str
    identifier_list = map(str, identifier_list)

    # make the base URL for the PubChem POST Request
    url = 'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/{}/assaysummary/{}'.format(identifier, output)

    # encoded_list = [requests.utils.quote(s) for s in identifier_list]

    # encoded_list = requests.utils.quote(','.join(identifier_list))
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    data = {identifier: ','.join(identifier_list)}

    response = requests.post(url, data=data)

    return response


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """ support function for bioprofile, used to create n equaled-sized
    sets from an iterable.
    """

    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


def generate_bioprofile(identifier_list, identifier='cid', outfile=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'bioprofile.csv'), chunk=False):
    num_compounds = len(identifier_list)

    # check to see whether
    # the list should be queried
    # in chunks of data or
    # processed as a whole
    if not chunk:
        chunk_size = num_compounds
    else:
        chunk_size = chunk

    counter = 0

    f = open(outfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    header_written = False

    for gp in grouper(identifier_list, chunk_size):
        batch = [cid for cid in gp if cid]
        response = bioassay_post(batch, identifier=identifier, output='csv')

        if response.status_code == 200:
            text = response.text
            if not header_written:
                f.write(text)
                header_written = True
            else:
                header = text.split('\n')[0]
                text = text.replace(header, '')
                f.write(text)
            counter = counter + len(batch)
        # else:
        #     f.close()
        #     os.remove(outfile)
        #     print("Error: {}".format(response.status_code))
        #     # return
    f.close()

    df = pd.read_csv(outfile)
    os.remove(outfile)
    return df
```

However, in the step while running the app in Docker:

`df = pd.read_csv(outfile, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)`

Flask returns an error:

```
2023-11-24 18:02:31 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1075, in perform_job
2023-11-24 18:02:31     rv = job.perform()
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 854, in perform
2023-11-24 18:02:31     self._result = self._execute()
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 877, in _execute
2023-11-24 18:02:31     result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/./app/tasks.py", line 257, in build_bioprofile
2023-11-24 18:02:31     preprofile = bp.generate_bioprofile(identifier_list)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/./app/bioprofile.py", line 90, in generate_bioprofile
2023-11-24 18:02:31     df = pd.read_csv(outfile, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
2023-11-24 18:02:31     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
2023-11-24 18:02:31     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 950, in read_csv
2023-11-24 18:02:31     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 605, in _read
2023-11-24 18:02:31     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1442, in __init__
2023-11-24 18:02:31     self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1753, in _make_engine
2023-11-24 18:02:31     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "/home/toxpro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 79, in __init__
2023-11-24 18:02:31     self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
2023-11-24 18:02:31   File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 554, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
2023-11-24 18:02:31 pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

While this error won't pop out in running separately on my computer.

I have tried several methods recommended by other questions, like adding parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv(outfile, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

But the results remain the same.

Or String IO:

```
from io import StringIO
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(outfile))
    os.remove(outfile)
    return df
```

But it returns a black csv file. Anyone knows how to write and read csv file in the Flask server properly?

Answer (score 0):

The questions has been solved. It was due to the identifier_list was blank due to previous errors in the app.